# Trouble appropriately constructing do while loops with correct conditions to run

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

I am struggling to correctly loop the code I have written to convert integers to roman numerals.

I have tried implementing a do while loop to run the code starting at "please enter an integer" and ending after my switch statement with the while part being: while(case "y" || "Y" == true )
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been searching through previous posts on stack overflow for a couple hours now and haven't been able to find anything that helps.

public class project8
{

```
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Project4
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to my integer  Roman numeral conversion program");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(" ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an integer in the range 1-3999 (both inclusive): ");
    int input = in.nextInt();
    if (input < 0 || input > 3999){
        System.out.println("Sorry, this number is outside the range.");
        System.out.println("Do you want to try again? Press Y for yes and N for no: ");
            String userInput = in.next();
                switch (userInput) {
                 case "N":
                 case "n":
                 System.exit(0);
                 break;

                 case "Y":
                 case "y":
                break;
                }   
            } 
    else if (input > 0 && input < 3999); 

      { System.out.println(Conversion.Convert(input));
        }          
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your `if - else if` conditions are redundant. You can use a simple `if - else` as input can only be in that range or not. `else if` makes only sence if you had two or more ranges to check, e.g.

```
if(input > 0 && input < 3999){ 
  ...
} 
else if (input > 4000 && input < 8000){ 
... 
} 
else { 
...
}
```

2) You don't need a switch block instead use the user input in your while condition as you want to continue looping when user input is Y/y, i.e `while(userChoice.equals("Y"))`

3) Use a `do - while` loop as you want that your application to run at least on time

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Welcome to my integer  Roman numeral conversion program");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(" ");

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    String choice;
    do{
        System.out.print("Enter an integer in the range 1-3999 (both inclusive): ");
        int input = in.nextInt();
        if(input > 0 && input < 3999){
            System.out.println(Conversion.Convert(input));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Sorry, this number is outside the range.");
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to try again? Press Y for yes and N for no: ");
        choice = in.next();
    }while(choice.equals("Y") || choice.equals("y"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me improve my code and understand loops better.